# React-redux could not find store

Tags: reactjs, express, redux, react-router, react-redux

I'm using React + Redux + Express. Whenever I reload my `localhost/courses`  I got an error not find 'store'. But if I go from `localhost -> click to nav course`, everything is working fine. How can I fix that?

**Error**

> Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or
>   props of "Connect(Course)". Either wrap the root component in a
>   Provider, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(Course)".

**store.js**

```
const middleware = applyMiddleware(promise(), thunk, logger());

export default createStore(reducer, middleware);
```

**App.js**

```
window.onload = () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} onUpdate={() => window.scrollTo(0, 0)}/>
    </Provider>
    , document.getElementById('main'));
};
```

**routes.js**

```
const routes = (
  <Route path='/' component={Layout}>
    <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
    <Route path='courses' data={data} component={Course}>          
  </Route>
);

export default routes;
```

**Course.js**

```
class Course extends React.Component {
  static contextTypes = {
    router: React.PropTypes.object,
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(fetchVocabulary());
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.words);
    return (
      <div>
        ...
      </div>
    );
  };
}

export default connect((store) => {
  return {
    words: store.vocabulary.words
  };
})(Course);
```

**package.json**

```
"react": "^15.4.1",
"react-dom": "^15.4.1",
"react-hot-loader": "^1.3.1",
"react-redux": "^5.0.1",
"react-router": "^3.0.0",
"redux": "^3.6.0",
"redux-logger": "^2.7.4",
"redux-promise-middleware": "^4.2.0",
"redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `browserHistory` , you need to use `historyApiFallback`

```
devServer: {
        historyApiFallback:true
    }
```

This uses `connect-history-api-fallback` to serve up `index.html` if the route doesn't match any other files and then all routes will be with respect to this file

Comment: Hi, is it possible to connect to a store only for the first time? I notice that my api response every time I click to nav /course. Thx

Comment: I am afraid I haven't tried that before and I don't have the answer to that

Comment: One more question: when I go to localhost/course, a page return 404 firstly, then go back to normally. I checked my console Network a status is 404. Have you ever met this problem?